# Lodash - check if object contains any of the key from the array

Tags: javascript, lodash

So I have an object and array. I want to check whether the object contains any of the keys from the array. Something like this:

Object:

```js
const user = {
    firstname: 'bob',
    lastname: 'boblastname'
    email: 'bob@example.com'
}
```

Arrays:

```
const lastname = ['lastname'];
const userDetails = ['firstname', 'email'];
```

So when checking for key existence it should return true.
Example:

```
_.includesKey(user, lastname) // true
_.includesKey(user, userDetails ) // true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know the question asks about lodash, but I always wonder why would you use a third party library to perform a rather trivial task

A way to approach the problem with the basic js tools could be

```js
const user = {
    firstname: 'bob',
    lastname: 'boblastname',
    email: 'bob@example.com'
}

const lastname = ['lastname'];
const userDetails = ['firstname', 'email'];


const hasLastName = lastname.every(prop => prop in user)
const hasDetails = userDetails.every(prop => prop in user)

console.log("has last name?", hasLastName)
console.log("has user details?", hasDetails)
```

it makes your project smaller by not bloating it with external libraries, it's most certainly faster and i'd argue it's even easier to read and understand.

Comment: You would use a third party library when you have to support older browsers that do not have the functionality you need. There are some of us that have to support decrepit versions of IE :)

Comment: Only the arrow functions there could have some retrocompatibility issue. The arrow function can easily be rewritten as standard functions. Worst case scenario you can use a transpiler. In general it looks like this is more retro-friendly than lodash ...

Comment: `every` is an ES5 function, not supported in IE8. I agree that if you can use a native function then it should be used. Also worth pointing out that lodash provides a way to package only the functions that you need if download speed is a problem.

Comment: but from what i read (from the main page) lodash is tested only against IE11. so I'd still rather pick a IE8 native support and then eventually use a transpiler to ES3 if needed.

Comment: This is technically a wrong answer as "I want to check whether the object contains *any* of the keys from the array." was requested. This checks that *all* of them are present. I guess `find` could be used instead of `every` (and to keep it as `true`/`false` result just `!!` the whole thing. `const hasDetails = !!userDetails.find(prop => prop in user)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some` and `intersection` and return true/false as result.

```js
const user = {
    firstname: 'bob',
    lastname: 'boblastname',
    email: 'bob@example.com'
}

const lastname = ['lastname'];
const userDetails = ['firstname', 'email'];

console.log(_.some(_.intersection(lastname, _.keys(user))))
console.log(_.some(_.intersection(userDetails, _.keys(user))))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```